# Google BigQuery same queries give different results

Tags: google-bigquery

I have run 2 very similar queries. The only difference is one is grouping by the names of the fields and the other one is grouping by the number of the fields (i.e. 1,2,3).

These 2 queries should be giving exactly the same result as there is no count distinct in the queries. However, it's not the case. One query gets 5 records and the other one gives only 1 record.

I am wondering if anyone could help.

Here are the job ids and queries:

Job ID 1: 631095067040:job_0NLPcGFK_umGVdyY0fuFnemkos0

> select Id, Channel 
>     from my.dataset 
>     where Id in ('aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd','eee')
>     group each by Id, Channel;

Job ID 2: 631095067040:job_NlWyxr0N4fi5ZnVKYDAVFr7qcew

> select Id, Channel 
>     from my.dataset 
>     where Id in ('aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd','eee')
>     group each by 1,2

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the queries in your question?

Comment: What is the difference between the 2 results? Is it just the order of the results?

Answer (score 2):

We (the BigQuery team) are tracking an issue where some queries are returning stale results (that is, return results that are based on stale data).

This issue has been resolved, please ping this thread or open another issue if you continue to see problems.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. Is it just an issue for this particular project? or across all projects? Thanks!

Comment: I am facing something similar in 2020. Using the same query, querying views of views which query tables, no streaming data, sometimes a row is present in the result, sometimes they are not. Have confirmed this by asking others to run the same query repeatedly

Comment: It's 2020 and I am facing the same issue - running same query multiple times (select only) and I am getting different results. Please specify how could we work around this. Saying it is resolved (when it isn't) is not an answer to the original question.