# Big Query Connection Error

Tags: connection, google-bigquery

We're getting a generic connection error on BQ

The screenshot of the error is attached here https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZXPU.jpg

I've read many post about this error and response from Google Engineers about a bug or some code path that generates this error. Please advice.

We have implemented a re-try logic where we sleep for 1 sec and try again, but it doesn't help. Please suggest any other work around.

Answer (score 1):

I looked into this.  The connection errors you observed were part of a temporary misrouting of queries which prevented them from executing successfully. This query routing issue was resolved shortly after your sample query completed. Apologies for the confusion.

This is was related to the underlying issue from another recent question:  [Google BigQuery same queries give different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245126/google-bigquery-same-queries-give-different-results)