# BigQuery returned inconsistent (= different) results of exactly same SELECT Query except for executing time

Tags: google-bigquery

The query is `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [table.click] WHERE time >= DATE_ADD('2015-03-25 06:00:00', -9, 'HOUR') AND time < DATE_ADD('2015-03-25 07:00:00', -9, 'HOUR')`

I wanted to fetch records with time of between 6 to 7.

```
[07:25:57] $ bq query "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [table.click] WHERE time >= DATE_ADD('2015-03-25 06:00:00', -9, 'HOUR') AND time < DATE_ADD('2015-03-25 07:00:00', -9, 'HOUR')"
Waiting on bqjob_r5e92dc9eca9622ed_0000014c4de50d59_1 ... (0s) Current status: DONE
+-----+
| f0_ |
+-----+
|   0 |
+-----+`
```

But the my process of importing data has worked for a long time and I confirmed this process is no problem (= streaming import between 6 to 7 worked well).

After 10 mins passed, I executed exactly same query.

```
[07:35:15]$ bq query "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [table.click] WHERE time >= DATE_ADD('2015-03-25 06:00:00', -9, 'HOUR') AND time < DATE_ADD('2015-03-25 07:00:00', -9, 'HOUR')"
Waiting on bqjob_r338acff11f068b44_0000014c4ded45c5_1 ... (2s) Current status: DONE    
+------+
| f0_  |
+------+
| 1954 |
+------+`
```

It worked well this time ! And after that, BigQuery has kept returning 1954 records like below.

```
[10:49:59]$ bq query "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [table.click] WHERE time >= DATE_ADD('2015-03-25 06:00:00', -9, 'HOUR') AND time < DATE_ADD('2015-03-25 07:00:00', -9, 'HOUR')"
Waiting on bqjob_r5693edc7523c1ca2_0000014c4e9f4f52_1 ... (0s) Current status: DONE    
+------+
| f0_  |
+------+
| 1954 |
+------+`
```

[Google BigQuery same queries give different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245126/google-bigquery-same-queries-give-different-results) is a similar question post, but `the BigQuery team` made a response that the issue is resolved, so I decide to issue this question post.

This problem happened twice. First time is `2015-03-24 22:00:00 JST ~ 2015-03-24 23:00:00 JST`, and second time is `2015-03-25 06:00:00 JST ~ 2015-03-25 07:00:00 JST`.

I attached a capture of `Google Cloud Status at the time that happened` that showed no system trouble of BigQuery globally.

[image: Google Cloud Status at the time that happened]

Comment: There is a small delay streaming inserted data is available for query. How many minutes have elapsed after your streaming insert was reported finished and you started to run your queries?

Comment: Thanks.

> There is a small delay streaming inserted data is available for query. 

Yes, I understand the delay like that.

Comment: > How many minutes have elapsed after your streaming insert was reported finished and you started to run your queries? 

At least 10 mins has elapsed, and at most 90 mins has elapsed.
I confirmed that all streaming inserts were reported finishing (flushing) at lease about 10 mins before the query run well. 

And `click` in my example above indicates that these data records are very sparse, and at the same time, more volume records (like `impression`) worked well. Considering this data volume, streaming insert about `click` data finished soon, and so at most 90 mins have elapsed.

Comment: i am facing this issue now in 2020, I have no streaming data, just using views to query other tables in BigQuery, sometimes rows are in the result, sometimes they are not..

Answer (score 1):

As Pentium10 pointed out, it seems that you were hit by the fact that there is a delay in streaming data.

Seems like your first query hit your data before the streaming insert propagate everywhere. Which is normal. Doesn't seem to be a matter of stale data, more a matter of, as was pointed out by Pentium, waiting for the delay after streaming data. 10 minutes seems a bit long maybe, but I don't see where the actual problem is.