# BigQuery giving success message , but not seemed to be saved, not shown in querying using web client from google

Tags: google-bigquery

Project number  :149410454586

We are facing the same issue mentioned below 
[BigQuery streaming insert data availability delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29347214/bigquery-streaming-insert-data-availability-delay)

We are getting the success response from BigQuery , but the data is not visible
while querying it.It is strange that it seemed to happen over a night, till then 
it was working fine.

We were supposed to go to deployment for UAT tomorrow and we never expected this 
heppen and now helpless, kindly if you could help out on this.

Comment: This issue has become a showstopper for us as ours is an analytic engine. The project is a billed project but we are in bronze support level now.

Comment: Report here https://groups.google.com/d/msg/bigquery-downtime-notify/O9di3uJPlqU/vsq1DiUI8bQJ. Subscribe to this list for timely announcements. Apologies for the inconveniences!

Answer (score 0):

Face the same issue one hour ago. Any streamed in data are not available for queries and it is not a warm-up issue.

Project Number: 272433143339

It seems to be related to https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/bigquery/18010

Comment: Report here https://groups.google.com/d/msg/bigquery-downtime-notify/O9di3uJPlqU/vsq1DiUI8bQJ. Subscribe to this list for timely announcements. Apologies for the inconveniences!