# What's the expected 'ingest' time on BigQuery Streaming inserts?

Tags: google-bigquery

This sounds like a repeat of [this year-old issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29347214/bigquery-streaming-insert-data-availability-delay) but I'm wondering if the BQ team has any further insight on why streaming inserts might take so long.  (I'm coming up on an hour for a mere 9K rows.)

Not sure if it's relevant but the only 'unusual' thing I'm doing is using python-pandas 'to_gbq' feature.  I actually collaborated with @felipehoffa on a write-up of this approach (see https://github.com/pmueller1/s3-bigquery-conga).  I'm using the if_exists='append' directive but the delay is happening from the first try (i.e when the table hasn't yet been created).  Not sure if that's helpful or not, but thought I'd throw it out there.

Answer (score 4):

Think I'll have to post my own answer on this one.  We were repeatedly getting 8hr+ ingest time on our streaming, so we switched to the cheaper, more reliable 'load' functions for our files.  I'm a pretty gung-ho BigQuery user, but there's something about streaming not-yet-ready-for-primetime.  We can't put our finger on what it is, but when it works, it works great.  When it doesn't, you land up waiting far too long to get your data available.  Until we can differentiate which case will happen, we're sort of steering clear of it for now.

Comment: Definitely improved!