# Google BigQuery Streaming Delay?

Tags: google-bigquery

We're using Google BigQuery streaming for streaming log on production and just got the data delay issue (1 hour and sometime much more).

There is no error during stream processing but we found the latest records displayed on BigQuery console are 1 hour+ ago.

The query that we use looks like...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  [TABLE]
order by timestamp desc
```

How could we check if this is normal or if we need to optimize streaming processing so the data will be inserted in BigQuery in nearly realtime manner?

I'm looking at this thread [BigQuery streaming insert data availability delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29347214/bigquery-streaming-insert-data-availability-delay) but not sure if this could be fixed by BigQuery team.

Thanks,

Comment: What is the name of the table in the dataset? Is `SELECT * FROM <your_table_name> ORDER BY timestamp DESC` the exact query that you are running?

Comment: Hi, we found this issue on most tables in this dataset.  

A new table will be created everyday (GMT+7) with the date suffix.  
 
For example, the table  PAY_AT_RETAIL_GENERATE_BARCODE_SUCCESS_20170725 is the table that has been created on 2017/07/25.  

We found the delay and data loss issues occurred from 2017/07/25 - 2017/08/10.  

I've verified today data and found that it's back to normal. I'm not sure if this issue occurred because the quota limit or if there are any issues on bigquery streaming issue during this period.

Comment: We haven't seen any issues on our side during this timeframe, and your streaming frequency looks fine in terms of quota. I would suggest using a partitioned table instead of creating a new one each day, though. If you see a problem in the future, please [post on the BigQuery issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0) and include the complete table name with project, dataset, and table.