# BigQuery Streaming Insert delay issue

Tags: google-bigquery

We're encountering issues with streaming inserts due to data hanging around in the streaming buffer for too long. We're using apache beam to read data from the streamed table every hour and copy it to a reconciled table. In order for this job to work as a delta, we let the batch job always get the latest timestamp (column on the streaming table populated with current timestmap at load time) that was loaded and use that for the next run. This method was used to avoid the issues that sometimes data is not available in a query as it's still in the buffer.

We now encountered issues that records still were missed as they had a lower timestamp (up to 30 minutes) than the max timestamp loaded at the previous run. I'm not sure how this could be possible as I would expect the streaming buffer to be flushed completely or not at all.

I've read similiar issues where apparently the table was malfunctioning and had to be fixed by Google (e.g. [BigQuery streaming insert data availability delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29347214/bigquery-streaming-insert-data-availability-delay)). Can you advise what can be done to fix this issue?

Comment: I also have the same problem here. Do you have any results with your case?